# Go to the last added image of the angular-bootstrap ngCarousel

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular6 along with the [ngbCarousel](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api)

I click a button to dynamically add a new image to the carousel and after that I want the carousel to actually go to the last image.

This is my code for adding a new image

```
  addpic(){
      //images is an array of json objs
      this.images.push({'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=7','name':'added one'});   
      let slide = 'ngb-slide-'+String(this.images.length);        
      this.carousel.select(slide);              
  }
```

The `slideId` follows the pattern of `ngb-slide-0`, so to go to the last slide I create that `slideId` and use the `select` to go there.

But this does not work, even though the new image is actually added and the           `this.carousel.select();` will work for other , existing images, like `this.carousel.select('ngb-slide-1');`

I have tried a stupid solution like

```
  addpic(){
      //images is an array of json objs
      this.images.push({'link':'https://picsum.photos/900/500/?image=7','name':'added one'});         
      this.carousel.select('ngb-slide-0');              
      this.carousel.prev();
  }
```

but it goes to the image that is last before the addition, and then to the previous of that.

How can I go to the newly added last image?

Thanks